# VSTO deployment file will not run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

I have been working on an outlook Addon using a visual studio VSTO project. When I run it as Debug or launch from within Visual studio Outlook (2016) launches and the addon works without an issue.

However, if I try to install it by navigating to the VSTO Deployment file and double click it I am presented with an error saying that ".net version 4 is not installed". I have attempted to run this as admin using the command line and am just presented with an error (this is because run as admin is missing if I right click on it).

The catch with this is that I've attempted to install the requested version of .net and am just told that it can't because I have a newer version installed.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I have logged into a machine using admin credentials and it installed without an issue. So I think it might be a system or group policy issue.

Comment: Are you aware of the publish feature?  If you right-click on your project and go to properties, there should be a 'publish' tab (I'm using VS 2013) and from there you can create a setup.exe installer to install the necessary prerequisites you need on the client machines, such as .net and VSTO.  This is known as the clickonce installer method.  If you need an .MSI, then you need to create a setup and deployment project in visual studio.

Comment: You are correct, we were eventually able to it this way this. The environment we were working with was what was presenting us with a lot of these issues.

If I get a chance I will update my initial post with some details on how we were able to build and deploy the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to deploy the application by invoking the application that is used to install VSTO files via the command line. This also allowed us to use a certificate when doing so.

The command used to install the certificate allowing it to run is [winhttpcertcfg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384088(v=vs.85).aspx) and then the exe VSTOInstaller.exe is ran with a path to the VSTO file as an argument using /i and then is done silently using /s.